# Proper display of Japanese and other special characters in Debian Linux

Tags: debian, fonts

I am running Debian, using the Terminus font. 
When I come across Japanese characters,
they are just displayed as rectangular boxes. 
This is the same for some other special characters
(I'm not sure which ones, as I can't see them).

An example of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Have you any Japanese / UTF-8 fonts installed at all? That's usually all that's needed for the display side of things. As long as the charset itself is not broken.

Comment: @frostschutz I don't think so. Which package should I install for that?

Comment: any you like, for example see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Japanese

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks, I installed ttf-takao-mincho and it fixed the problem